# keyboard hiding my textview

Tags: iphone, uiview, keyboard, uiscrollview, uitextview

i have a simple app, it consist of 2 textview, 1 uiview as a coretext subclass, and then 1 scrollview. the others part is subviews from scrollview. I use this scrollview because i need to scroll the textviews and uiview at the same time. I already scroll all of them together, but the problem is, the keyboard hiding some lines in the textview. I have to change the frame of scrollview when keyboard appear, but it still not help.
This is my code :

```
UIScrollView *scrollView;
UIView *viewTextView;
UITextView *lineNumberTextView;
UITextView *codeTextView;


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 addObserver:self 
 selector:@selector(keyboardWillAppear:) 
 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
 object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 addObserver:self 
 selector:@selector(keyboardWillDisappear:) 
 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
 object:nil];

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 88, self.codeTextView.frame.size.width, 
                                           self.codeTextView.frame.size.height);

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, viewTextView.frame.size.height);

[scrollView addSubview:viewTextView];

CGAffineTransform translationCoreText = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(60, 7);
[viewTextView setTransform:translationCoreText];

[scrollView addSubview:lineNumberTextView];
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.codeTextView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

}

```
-(void)keyboardWillAppear:(NSNotification *)notification {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:[[[notification userInfo] 
                               objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]]; 
CGRect keyboardEndingUncorrectedFrame = [[[notification userInfo] 
                                          objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey ] CGRectValue];
CGRect keyboardEndingFrame = 
[self.view convertRect:keyboardEndingUncorrectedFrame 
              fromView:nil];


self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 88, self.codeTextView.frame.size.width, 
                                           self.codeTextView.frame.size.height - keyboardEndingFrame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

```
-(void)keyboardWillDisappear:(NSNotification *) notification {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:[[[notification userInfo] 
                               objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]]; 
CGRect keyboardEndingUncorrectedFrame = [[[notification userInfo] 
                                          objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGRect keyboardEndingFrame = 
[self.view convertRect:keyboardEndingUncorrectedFrame 
              fromView:nil];


self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 88, self.codeTextView.frame.size.width, 
                                           self.codeTextView.frame.size.height + keyboardEndingFrame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

can somebody help me please?

**UPDATE**
this is a pic from this problem :

[image]

some text still hiding by the keyboard after i do my code

**UPDATE AGAIN**
i think the keyboard still hiding the text because i set the textview scroll enable to be NO. is that right??

i have add this code to the keyboardwillappear method

`codeBuilderSelectedRange = self.codeTextView.selectedRange;
    [self.viewTextViewScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (CGFloat)codeBuilderSelectedRange.location) animated:YES];`

but it just make the textview dissappear from the view...can somebody tell the answer?

Comment: where is your TextView delegate method , in your delegate method set you scroll view frame and then you can scroll you text view and your view both of them when keyboard is appear

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma mark -------------------------
#pragma mark TextView delegate Methods
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 44)];

    UIButton *infoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 6, 60, 32)];

    [infoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"back-btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [infoButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    infoButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];

    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(resignTextView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [parentView addSubview:infoButton];

    [infoButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *customBarButtomItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:parentView];

    [parentView release];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarButtomItem;

    [customBarButtomItem release];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;


    self.scrollView.frame.size.height = 206;

    //[self.view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,320)];
}



- (void)resignTextView {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;


    self.scrollView.frame.size.height = 460;

    [messageTextView resignFirstResponder];


    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer. But i had something error, and i want to ask u, it is possible to do self.scrollView.frame.size.height = 206; ?? because the error msge is show that "Lvalue required as left operand assignment"

Comment: yes it is possible to do because i have used  this many time in many project and it is working

Comment: You can't directly assign height property. You'll have to get the frame, modify it and reassign it like this: CGRect rect = self.scrollView.frame; rect.size.height = 206; self.scrollView.frame = rect;

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that I have used.  Basically, what we're going to do is animate the position of the view whenever a `UITextField` gets focus.  To do this, we must make our `UIViewController` a delegate of our `UITextField`s

The first delegate method you need to implement is `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

```
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds 
                                                fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds
                                           fromView:self.view];

    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 
            * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y 
            - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
            * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Now that the view has been 'pushed up' when a `UITextField` is selected, we want to make sure that we slide it back down when we're done:

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

[This was taken](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html) from one of my favorite Cocoa blogs, [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com).  Cheezy name, but Matt's got some great posts on Objective-C development.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for UITextView (not UITextField)

you may have a look at the following tutorial: http://codingcluster.blogspot.in/2012/03/iphone-make-uitextview-move-up-when.html

i have implemented it and it is working as expected(at least for me)